# RT LOGGER not writing to a file [RT]

Tags: perl, rt

I created an action module in RT. And I want to output the RT Logger into text file. I already configured RT_SiteConfig.pm with:

```
Set($LogToSyslog    , 'info');
Set($LogToScreen    , 'info');
Set($LogToFile , 'debug');
Set($LogToFile, 'info');
Set($LogToFile, 'warning');
Set($LogToFile, 'error');
Set($LogDir, '/tmp');
Set($LogToFileNamed , "rt.log");
```

And I created action module:

```
    package RT::Action::SetLoggingInfo;

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use base 'RT::Action';

    sub Prepare {
        my $self = shift;

        $RT::Logger->info('Logging info');
        $RT::Logger->info('Logging dump info');

        return 1; # True if Commit should run, false if not
    }

    sub Commit {
        my $self = shift;

       

        return 1; 
    }

    1;
```

And all I want it output the string inside RT::Logger to the logging file (rt.log) in /tmp. But it doesn't work, whenever I tried to create object in the web cli, there's nothing log in the rt.log file. I was testing in the rt-test server, not in production. I would likely have this kind of results.

Can you help me how to achieve this? Thanks so much.

Comment: *"all I want it output the string inside RT::Logger"* I am not familiar with this software, could you please provide links to the `RT::Logger` module and its source code. This will help clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you have too many directives `$LogToFile` in your config file. There should be only one of this type, if not, the last takes all. So you've set to log the `errors` but your module logs `info`. Consult the [documentation](https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/4.4.4/RT_Config.html#Logging) to see how the log levels work. If you set log level to error, the logging process omits all debug, info, notice and warning events.